# Can electrons move through vacuum?

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, vacuum, electronics

I studied that electronics is the branch of physics which deals with the practical applications of moving electrons through vacuum, semi-conductors and gasses. Can electrons move through vacuum?

Comment: Just our of curiosity, why would you imagine there was a problem with it? After all there would be nothing in the way ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. That is the operating principle of [this device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube), among many others:
[image]

Comment: This is a fun answer LOL :-D, +1

Comment: Sad thing is, in twenty years kids will have to ask their grandparents what this huge smartphone has to do with electrons in vacuum. Oh well, at least there'll still be electron tunnelling in MOSFETs, I guess...

Answer (score -3):

I’m no physicist but I have ideas, inventions that could revolutionize the way we travel. Using electro induction we can actually cancel inertia. Gravity on earth is made from the influence of electrostatic fields. When an electron is negatively charged and the inside structure is powered high enough. You become repelled from earth but attracted to the negative field amongst the crust. I need someone that knows the math to help me.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/369084)